# Merging / consolidating multiple SQL instances into one

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

We have a SQL Server 2008 R2 machine with ~10 instances on it.

Is there a way to consolidate this 10 instances into a single instance transparently to the applications (= no need to find / modify all the connection settings).

I don't ask how to move the DBs / logins from one instance to another (backup + login scripting will help with this), but I have no idea how e.g. CRM can still access its DB on `server1\crm` after I moved the DB to the main instance of `server1`

Reasons: easier to manage, better resource distribution (RAM / CPU), cheaper if you want to buy 3rd-party monitoring / backup programs because they are licensed often per instance and not per server (except RedG..e)

Answer (score 0):

[server aliases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190445%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) can be a viable solution.

the downside is that they must be set on the client machine so if you happen to have hundreds of servers hosting applications you have to set the aliases on all of them.

[here](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/02/09/how-to-configure-a-sql-server-alias-for-a-named-instance-on-a-development-machine) is a tutorial about configuring aliases with some detail; the msdn page is quite skinny...